# Gravar/Alterar input de mesmas IDs

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde galera.

Estou com uma duvida sobre a gravação de varias inputs com mesmo id no Mysql, ja procurei varias paginas e não consegui ainda uma solução de como fazer.
Tenho um cadastro de cliente, que atualmente encontra-se em uma unica tabela, e estou fazendo com que seja gravado cada parte do cadastro em uma tabela.
E na seção que estou, funciona assim tenho o codigo

```
       <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
            <div class="box box-solid box-info">

            <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">CAIXA 1</h3>
        </div>

       <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Versão</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="versao[]" id="vpos" data-inputmask="'mask': ['99.99.99', '999999']" data-mask>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Layout</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vpos[]" id="vpos" data-inputmask="'mask': ['99.99', '9999']" data-mask>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Numero Série:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nserie[]" id="nserie" placeholder="Numero de Série" data-inputmask="'mask': ['999999999-99', '99999999999']" data-mask >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Código Ativação</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codativ[]"  id="codativ" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><label>Código Segurança</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codseg[]" id="codseg">
        </div>
```

e tenho 5 tabs e todos inputs tem mesmo name, porem os tabs tem suas ids.
E nesse caso, qual seria o modo correto para eu utilizar, para depois retornar os dados nas mesmas tabs.
Uma clareada para eu seguir o caminho.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos o esquema do array usando os mesmos nomes, mas achei confuso. Será que não fica mais simples usar ao invés de arrays de names usar nomes como tab1_versao, tab2_versao, tab3_versao... , tab1_vpos, tab2_vpos, tab3_vpos... etc?

Comment: pelo que entendi vc diz para eu criar novas colunas na tabela?

Comment: Não precisa criar novas colunas, mas se tem que diferenciar os inputs por aba você vai ter que renomea-los. Outra solução é usar `versao[tab1]`, `vpos[tab1]`. Quando esse input chega no back-end ai você separa os valores corretamente e grava nas colunas originais.

Comment: Certinho, só uma questão, que me retornou o erro, na gravação do form no banco, que tenho 10 tabelas relacionadas, eu utilizei o Inner Join nessa forma
foreach($_POST["versao"] as $versao);
foreach($_POST["vpos"] as $vpos);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE * FROM cliente 
 inner join dados_cliente on cliente.idc = dados_cliente.id;

assim seguindo outros Inner, porem com erro